# Метод масштабирования текста для сайта

Tags: css3, jquery, css

Уважаемые, подскажите метод масштабирования текста для сайта.

Comment: по какому событию у тебя должно происходить масштабирование?
Может просто менять размер шрифта через js?

Comment: события никакого просто текс должен масштабироваться в зависимости от размера экрана

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Насколько я понял, вы имеете ввиду изменить размер текста. Ну а если вы имели ввиду другое, измените вопрос*

---

Представим что у вас есть какой-нибудь блок с текстом (а если его нет, то надо создать). Выглядеть это дело должно так:

```
<p>some text</p>
```

Нам нужно добавить к блоку id:

```
<p id="1234">some text</p>
```

Теперь с помощью скрипта обращаемся к блоку и меняем font-size:

```
document.getElementById('1234').style.fontSize = 'необходимый_размер';
```

Размер нужно указывать согласно [этим правилам](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/size)

**UPDATE1** Если нужно только 'подстраивание под экран' используйте js-код:

```
document.getElementById('1234').style.fontSize = screen.width / 500 + 'ex'
```

Answer (score 2):

[CSS Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries) вам в помощь.